# Whether the polynomial rings $R[X,Y]$ is equal to $R[Y,X]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

In J. Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra part I, the author gives an exercise:
A-3.32. (i) If $R$ is a nonzero commutative ring, show that $R[X,Y]\neq R[Y,X]$.
The author defines polynomial rings in one indeterminate as the set of finite sequences with pointwise addition and convolution product. He extends the definition to more than one indeterminate as $R[X_1,\dots, X_{n+1}]=R[X_1,\dots, X_n][X_{n+1}]$.
In $R[X]$ he defines the indeterminate $X= (0,1,0,\dots)$.
He has provided a hint that: In $R[X,Y]=R[X][Y]$, the indeterminate $Y=(0,1^*,0,\dots)$, where $1^*$ is the unit element of $R[X]$; that is, $1^*=(1,0,\dots)$, where 1 is the unit element of $R$. In $R[Y,X]=R[Y][X]$, we have $Y=(0,1,0,\dots)$.
I couldn't see how this hint solves the problem. It will be better if someone helps me to proceed in the problem.
The second part of the problem is saying that this two polynomial rings are isomorphic, which seems quite clear to me. But I am stuck at the above question.

Can I just say since $1^*\neq 1$ so these two rings are not the same?

Comment: As tuples, $x = ((0,1,0,0,\dots), 0, 0, \dots)) \in R[x][y]$ and $y =(0, (1,0,0, \dots), 0, 0, \dots) \in R[x][y]$, where the outer tuple has entries from $R[x]$ and inner tuple, as an element in $R[x]$, has entries from $R$.

Comment: and if you stack each of entries in $R[x][y]$ to have a matrix (which is a finite matrix since our objects are polynomials) , we can see that $x=\begin{pmatrix} 0& 1& 0& \dots \\ 0& 0& 0& \dots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$ and $y = \begin{pmatrix} 0& 0& 0& \dots \\ 1& 0& 0& \dots \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots\end{pmatrix}$.  Note that the matrix form $M$ of $f(x,y) \in R[x][y]$ satisfies $$f(x,y) = (1, y, y^2, \dots) M  \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ x^2 \\ \vdots \end{pmatrix}$$ by its construction.

Comment: and so the isomorphism $R[x][y] \to R[y][x]$ will be nothing but something like the matrix transposition. Note that two polynomial rings are not the same, but they are isomorphic.

Comment: It seems to me that if the underlying set of $R[X]$ is defined as finite sequences in $R$, then in fact $R[X]=R[Y]$ as sets.  And then a finite sequence over $R[X]$ or $R[Y]$ would again be elements from the same set.  This makes me question the wisdom of posing the question with this definition.  That’s *really* how he does it?!

Comment: I agree with rschwieb here. Both $R[X][Y]$ and $R[Y][X]$ are just sets of infinite matrices with finite rows and columns, by definition. $X$'s and $Y$'s are just syntax sugar and they actually mean different things in $R[X][Y]$ and $R[Y][X]$. Identity function on underlying sets, therefore, does $1\mapsto 1$, $X\mapsto Y$, $Y\mapsto X$, while matrix transposition does $1\mapsto 1$, $X\mapsto X$, $Y\mapsto Y$.

Comment: Could you explain why matrix transposition sends $X$ to $X$ and $Y$ to $Y$? @Ennar

Comment: @Nabakumar Bhattacharya, look at the comment by dust05, and observe what matrices $x$ and $y$ are in $R[x][y]$. You can get $y$ by transposing $x$ and vice versa. However, in $R[y][x]$, $x$ and $y$ switch places compared to $R[x][y]$, so the map $1\mapsto 1$, $x\mapsto x$, $y\mapsto y$ looks like it should be identity, but it is not, since we used the same symbols to denote different matrices in different cases. The map is in fact transposition.

Comment: I think rachwieb is right too.